# Did Wittgenstein say something about intuition for logic?

Tags: logic, wittgenstein

When one creates some logical content, like in programming, only naives think that this is a rational way of thinking. In fact, this is based on patterns and intuition.

Did Wittgenstein say anything about this?

Comment: Can you give us some hints as to why you think Wittgenstein would have said something to the effect that only the naive think they are creating logical content? I'm not a Wittgenstein scholar but that doesn't exactly jive with anything I remember from reading Wittgenstein.

Comment: *only naives think that this is a rational way of thinking. In fact, this is based on patterns and intuition.* ->  As a programmer, I gotta say if programming is done via intuition and not reasoning, then your definition of "reasoning" probably excludes all thinking.  Can you explain what you mean a little more?  It is interesting, at least.

Comment: @goldilocks  As another programmer. I would agree with the OP.  There is a level of operation that Heidegger calls 'expertise', like fluency in a language, and in that state, your actions are driven by taste and unconscious experience  most of the time.  When you have to actually 'think' consciously, you are falling back on pre-expert patterns, which the naive imagine are your normal patterns of action.

Comment: @jobermark I don't disagree with your answer but there is an unsubtle difference between "only the naive imagine this is *conscious*" (your phrase) and "only  naives think that this is a *rational* way...".  I don't see a conflict between reason and intuition the way you've described, if the later refers to learned patterns that have *become* unconscious, they are rational mechanisms.

Comment: @goldilocks  It is a matter of chopping logic.  Is taste rational?  The OP and I would probably say that it is not, even when well tuned by the environment to be correct and valuable, a rational process.  I understand that rationally tempered taste can continually accord with rational thought, especially when monitored and corrected systematically.  But that does not make it the same thing at the point of application.  (I am also giving the OP some benefit of the doubt about language.)

Comment: @jobermark I've been thinking about this a bit and to refine: practising a craft involves moments of more and less *conscious* detail; going with the way I understand your answer, the more "less" moments are more intuition based (BTW, if those are *learned* mechanisms they certainly are very different than *taste*).  During the process ("point of application") a craftsperson makes a series of conscious, rational decisions to "go with what s/he knows", i.e., trust his/her experience and intuition with a high degree of certainty.

Comment: Actually what I'm curious about is whether @Gergly has anything in mind to which this analysis does *not* apply, i.e., if there is a "more rational" way of thinking than just described, a rational way of thinking which does *not* often depend upon skilled intuition.

Comment: @goldilocks As I read him, Wittgenstein would, in fact, say no, there is no form of rationality that does not base a language-game, and there are no language-games that are fully and implicitly logical.

Comment: Also, you can adapt to other's vocabulary, or not.  You clearly know what I mean.  Constantly objecting to the wording is just gauche :) .

Comment: @jobermark Yeah, I believe I follow and I'm down with that (I would agree this applies to any activity) -- just I think the OP's wording lacks some necessary nuance.  It could be taken to mean something quite different, e.g., something used to distinguish one kind of activity from another that is "intuition free".

Comment: @goldilocks, I cannot come up with a situation where rationality wins over intuition. In programming one seldom consults programming language semantics, which are considered par excellence rational constructs. But if you step one level up, writing a programming language semantics cannot be fully rational as you cannot foresee all applications of a yet to be designed language. You can be aspect-blind. You must lean on your intuition: this language will be used this-and-this way. And you might well be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heidegger calls this point where a logical context allows intuition to function efficiently the state of being 'expert'.  It dominates most of the experience of most programmers or other craftsmen most of the time, and when it fails, there is a specific feeling of 'being thrown' out of context.  (For outside touchstones, expertise is the quality of 'quality' in 'Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance' and is the mechanical aspect of Integrity (the 'Te') in some interpretations of the Tao Te Ching.  It is the feeling you are most effective when not thinking.)

The context of expertise is a lot like what Wittgenstein calls a language-game, only local.  The rules are unclear, but everyone has adapted to them, and this co-adaptation allows most action to be based on taste and unconscious experience.

Only the naive imagine that what goes on in the writing of prose is mostly conscious.  Our grammar and rhetorical sense passes below a given level of cognitive demand when we achieve real fluency, and we enter the 'game' of writing as real players.  Wittgenstein would claim that all thinking, even deep philosophical reasoning has this same character, that there are no interactive processes that do not become 'language-games' in this sense for most of the participants.

The two points of view are kind of complementary takes on the same thing.  Wittgenstein was focused on how much of the game-rules we do not need to learn in order to play well, and how philosophy backs off to see the rules and tell when you are adapting them to new purposes, and when you are just outside them.  He is fascinated by how much we know without knowing that we know it.  Philosophy becomes a game of determining when we would be better of knowing what we do and do not know, and when we would in fact not be better off learning that.

The notion of expertise is instead focused on how much of what we *could* be doing consciously we would rather abandon to automatic processes, and how little we communicate about this state, and therefore most of our experience.  We are experts at living, and real understanding explains that expert realm, not just the underlying pre-expert mechanical details.  (The emphasis in computing is then on creating convincing phenomena that keep someone in a state of expertise most of the time without abandoning them completely when they are 'thrown'.  You want things to be automatic, but not so automatic that one is thoroughly unaware of the underlying rules when one has to think through an unfamiliar situation.)

Comment: I'm sorry. What on earth do you mean by mechanical aspect of Te 徳　? The word means excellence or virtue.

Comment: I haven't read Heidegger on this but on some others things (e.g. *Being and Time*) and he tends to use words in transplanted ways -- or (I think) unique compounded German words that loose their unique connotation when translated.  I just mention this because **intuition** here strikes me as one of those and googling around implies he actually refers to several different kinds of "intuition".  What you've described here is probably not so different than contemporary mainstream psychologies of expertise.

Comment: @virmaior The word means something that does not translate.  There are interpretations of Lao Tzu from positions other than complete religious acceptance.  Such translators interpret it in the way I am referencing tend to translate it as 'integrity' or some other word referring to completeness, over sheer value (see Victor Mair's).  "The master does not act, and things are accomplished." captures the basic feeling behind 'flow' and expertise.

Comment: @goldilocks I am just attributing to Heidegger because my sources (from the early 1990's) do so.  They may be reaching.  There is a spate of books on interface design from that era that shifted the domain away from aesthetics and goal-orientation and toward psychological considerations and contextual learning.

Comment: @jobermark No, really the translations of 徳 as "integrity" is out of the norm even for  a philosophical translation. A better non-religious translation is "power" as suggested by Roger Ames and David Hall.  This seems to only be the translation of Mair -- http://www.amazon.com/Tao-Te-Ching-Classic-Integrity/dp/055334935X -- who isn't a philosopher. The normal chinese word for integrity is 忠 which occurs in documents as old as the Tao Te Jing...

Comment: The point is that it has at least five different translations, by you presume to tell me which to use.  It is a side-point anyway.  Get over your meddling.